# Resume form submission afer ajax call

Tags: jquery

I am work on a project using **codeigniter** which is MVC. I am having issue trying to redirect users to another page: http://users.com. There is code in the models that should redirect if everything works fine. Instead to process the form on success call, it was only reloading the page again. Thank you very much for any help in advance.

**My code below:**

```js
$('input[data-post]').on('click', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();

    var output = $('div.message');
    
    $.ajax({
        url: $('form').attr('action'),
        method: "POST",
        data: $('form').serialize(),
        success: footprint
    });

    function footprint(response, statusText){
        if(response){
            output.html(response);
            // console.log(response);
        }else{
            setTimeout(function(){
                $('form').attr('action', 'http://users.com');
                $('form').submit();
                // console.log('success');
            },5000);
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try change to:

```
    setTimeout(function(){
        window.location.href = 'http://users.com';
    },5000);
```